# ESlint: Parsing error: Unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have this function:

```
import React from 'react';
import FilterList from './Filter/FilterList';

export default function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FilterList />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And included these packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"i18n-react": "^0.4.0",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.31.2",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
"rxjs": "^5.4.3",
"superagent": "^3.5.2",
"webpack": "^3.5.4"},

"devDependencies": {
"eslint": "^4.4.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.3.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
"nwb": "0.18.x",
"nwb-less": "^0.6.0",
"yaml-loader": "^0.5.0"},
```

But when running lint I get this error:
error  Parsing error: Unexpected token <

my .eslintrc file:

```
module.exports = {
"extends": "airbnb-base",
"plugins": [
  "import"
]};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please add more information about your presets-plugins, can you share your .babelrc? are you using eslint-babel?

Comment: Q is updated with my eslint file.

Comment: this seems to be more like an error that would arise from your .babelrc or webpack configuration then ESlint

Comment: could be. I didn't really setup webpack. If I remove the webpack package I get the same error. I guess webpack is used by nwb.

Comment: this link should help you: [eslint-plugin-react issue #447](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/447#issuecomment-184617282)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this error because eslint don't know how to handle JSX syntax, and you need `eslint-plugin-react` for this.

But you are also missing other plugins required for airbnb-eslint-config to work. Do what they say in docs which is:

`npm info "eslint-config-airbnb@latest" peerDependencies`

and install printed dependencies (as dev dependencies).

As of today I get this list:

```
{ eslint: '^3.19.0 || ^4.3.0',
  'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y': '^5.1.1',
  'eslint-plugin-import': '^2.7.0',
  'eslint-plugin-react': '^7.1.0' }
```

Comment: Does this answer also apply if one is using Vue instead of React?

Comment: @JayBienvenu for Vue you are going to probably use this: https://eslint.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `nmp5+`, one shortcut would be:

```
npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb
```

The `-peerdeps` refers to all the dependences.

Answer (score 0):

If every peer dependency is added and you still get this error, be sure to check that your eslint config has the following options:

```json
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true,
        "modules": true
    }
}
```